# How to alert if user tries to click a disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible for Jquery or Javascript to capture a click on a disabled radio button, and alert the user to do something else first. As far as I know, I could not find any way to capture a mouse over or click event on a disabled radio button.

Please advise if this is possible. Thanks.

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="radio"][disabled]').click(function() {
    alert('waffles');
});
```

jQuery doc reference: [attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (`[type="radio"]`), [has-attribute-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) (`[disabled]`).

If the radio buttons can be dynamically added, you'll need to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"][disabled]', function() {
```